# Issue Gathering Ethernet Error Metrics on Ubuntu with Intel X550 NIC

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

I am working on some cable benchmarking and have been having some problems gathering accurate ethernet error statistics. When running traffic generation software, I found that the OS counters (both ifconfig and /proc/net/dev) always have ethernet errors at 0 even though typically well performing ethernet have at least 1 in 1012 bit error rate (probably worse since I am using a lossy cable). I am wondering if there is some other place I can look for ethernet metrics. Why does the OS not seem to update the packet errors? Are packets with errors dropped automatically and not counted? Is there some issue with my current NIC/driver/kernel combo? Any tips on how to get more accurate measurements?

Current my setup is 2 linux Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS servers with a 10gE ethernet running between both. I am using 2 NICs and a cat6 cable going between both servers that supports 10gE. The NIC is using Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 4.2.1-k.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

No errors is probably correct, and there is no reason to suspect that this is due to a interface problem between your OS and NIC.

I run a network with multiple Cisco switches at work, and have traffic counters currently in the triple digits terabyte range - and error counters of **all** interfaces are nil. Zero. No errors detected.

You can get more statistics about your NIC with `ethtool -S interface`, e.g. `ethtool -S eth0`:

```
$ sudo ethtool -S eth0
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 678773569
     rx_packets: 558920576
     tx_errors: 1
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 20
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 558918071
     broadcast: 2494
     multicast: 11
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0
```

That's from a Linux machine with ~1TiB of traffic in total.

Typically your switch, if you have a managed switch, will also have interface counters. On Cisco `show interfaces counters` should give you the counters, including errors. Expect it to show 0 errors.